# RDF and SPARQL: How to ask for an object of a property that is a subclass

Tags: sparql, rdf, modeling, rdfs

I am getting into RDF modeling and have difficulties of applying properties with subClasses. I want to model a set of people and their capabilities in RDF and then want to query for people. For example, given the following RDF stuff:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix d: <http://mytest.de/data#>
prefix s: <http://mytest.de/types#>

d:runningFast rdfs:subClassOf d:running .
d:myPerson s:does d:runningFast .

s:does rdfs:domain s:Person.
s:does rdfs:range s:Capability.
```

... I want to find the persons that are capable of running in general. The following works for this purpose:

```
select ?person {  
  ?person s:does ?o.
  ?o rdfs:subClassOf* d:running.           
 }
```

But as the example is getting more complex, I would like to do it without the indirection via `?o`. I want to do it this way:

```
select ?person {  
  ?person s:does d:running.           
 }
```

What am I missing? I suspect it is some additional information necessary for s:does, as I can get the sample working with `rdf:type` instead of `s:does`.

I was expecting that `?person s:does d:running` would work as well, since d:runningFast is a subclass of d:running.

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to do it this way" - if the data is given in its current form, then you have to do it like in the first query. the only more compact way is `?person s:does/rdfs:subClassOf* d:running. `

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was expecting that `?person s:does d:running` would work as well, since d:runningFast is a subclass of d:running.

Comment: ehm, but *how* and *why* should this work? SPARQL is exact matching of triples, anything beyond is inference which has to be supported and enabled by the used triple store. Moreover, what you expect won't be covered by any standard reasoning profile